# Laravel query getting count(*) instead of distinct id

Tags: laravel, laravel-4.2

I'm really stumped on this. I'm using Laravel 4.2 to develop a web application in PHP, and I keep getting messed up results on our contacts page. Basically, the first step in this feature is to get a filtered list of contacts starting with a list of contact ids (with some additional criteria in the query for which contacts to select) and manipulate the list later on in my code. I believe there is an issue with that query that is messing things up later on, and I'm not sure why. So, here is my query, pared down to just the part of the query to get all the contact ids, rather than ones that meet a criteria:

```
$contacts = DB::table('contacts')
    ->select(DB::raw('distinct contacts.id'))
    //other filtering criteria that doesn't seem to be the source of the problem
    ->whereRaw('contacts.id in (' . $contact_ids_string . ') ');
```

where $contact_ids_string is a string I built earlier in the code containing the contact ids (I kept getting weird errors trying to bind $contact_ids to the query, so I just did it this way.

Anyway, I keep getting weird results, so I introduced a typo into the query to get an error message so I could look at the query that was being built, and here is the query (with the typo removed):

select count(*) as aggregate from 'contacts' where contacts.id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

I think the problem might be that the query contains count(*) rather than distinct contacts.id, which is what I want.

Any ideas why this is happening, and how to resolve it? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using Laravel 4 in 2017?

Comment: There is a weird thing in your database design or code, the idea of id is to be unique, so you shall no use `distinct contacts.id`.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu, he may be working on old code base. I currently have Laravel 4.1 based project with no migrations or even FKs in the database..

Comment: for debugging you can try `\DB::enableQueryLog();` before the query and `dd(\DB::getQueryLog());` right after the query, it will print the SQL query being generated, but don't forget to remove that after debugging is done...

Comment: @ShadyAtef I didn't include all the joins for simplicity, but there is a has-many relationship in there, and my assumption is that if I simply used select contacts.id, that I would get multiple rows with the same id because of the join where more than one of another entity belongs to contacts. Is this assumption incorrect?

Comment: @Akshay Khale If I used that, where would I be able to view the query log?

Comment: @AWeston, your assumption is right, but  people can't help you if you write a query and ask on the results of other that you don't mention